Stepper motor missing steps, how to solve?
I have a small Nema stepper motor, think it is a bipolar stepper motor. The motor does not react as expected, since the motor has a step angle of 1.8°, one turn should be 200 steps. Yet the stepper executes one turn with 50 steps. I have tried multiple coil sequences, which have not resulted in any success. Even tied half-step sequences, which I would at least expect the motor to execute a turn with 100 steps.
The stepper motor is a SUMTOR 28HS28064XG, and is specified on the label to have 1.8° and 0.6A. It is controlled with a DRV8833 () and microcontroller. I have now multiple times checked the connection between MCU<->DRV8833<->stepper, which seems to be correct – even tried different stepper sequences, which reflect a wrongly connected stepper motor. For the DRV8833 chip, no information is given in the datasheet about the stepper motor usage link: Datasheet DRV8833.
The stepper motor is currently only controlled in switching on and off the stepper coils. Below is the stepping sequence currently tested, which neither results in a 200-step turn. The half-step sequence does not change anything noticeable.

Can anyone let me know how to troubleshoot this further? The half-step sequence should result in half-steps, right? With a step angle of 1.8°, 200 steps per turn are expected?
Could the step sequence be wrong?
Thanks

When you say it completes a revolution in 50 steps, is that 50 runs through the table you've labelled step 1 through step 4 (1-4 repeated fifty times)? or 50 total (1-4 repeated twelve times then 1,2).

If the former then it appears to work correctly - 50 x 4 = 200 steps. 360/200=1.8degree per step.

What is the 8833 plugged into? Some clone boards have the connections between the step selector jumpers and the IC socket implemented incorrectly, so the jumpers do not affect the step selection at all. There are several diagrams which can be found online for identification of and modification to the board.

Can you monitor current into VM pin? Or better still, monitor voltage across AISEN and/or BISEN ground resistors? Current should be more-or-less constant for each phase of the 4-step sequence. The 8-step sequence (half-step) current is not so constant, but never goes close to zero.

one turn with 50 steps ... how is this a description of missing steps? ... it's more a description of  extra steps

Data sheet for stepper?
